# how to send an audio stream via tcp in a thread in Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, audio, tcp

I'm trying to send an audio stream from a microphone via TCP in a thread other than the main thread. Therefore I've set up a server an I'm listening for incoming connections. Once a client connects, I want to send it the audio stream. I've read the Qt Documentation about QTcpServer, Multithreading, and QtMultimedia. I've also looked at [this](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QUdpSocket.php) website for example code about multithreading and TCP servers in Qt. The problem is this message that I get during runtime:

**QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread. (Parent is QNativeSocketEngine(0xae802a78), parent's thread is MyThread1(0x1856d28), current thread is QThread(0x1838aa0)**

this is my code:

in file myserver.h

```
#ifndef MYSERVER_H
#define MYSERVER_H

#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <mythread.h>
#include <QtMultimediaKit/QAudioFormat>
#include <QtMultimediaKit/QAudioInput>
#include <QtMultimediaKit/QAudioDeviceInfo>


class MyServer : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyServer(QObject *parent = 0);
    void startServer();

signals:

public slots:

protected:
    void incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor);

private:
    QAudioInput *audioInput;
};

#endif // MYSERVER_H
```

in file myserver.cpp

```
#include "myserver.h"

MyServer::MyServer(QObject *parent) :
    QTcpServer(parent)
{
}

void MyServer::startServer()
{
    int port = 12345;

    QString ipAddress;
    QList<QHostAddress> ipAddressesList = QNetworkInterface::allAddresses();

    for (int i = 0; i < ipAddressesList.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (ipAddressesList.at(i) != QHostAddress::LocalHost &&  ipAddressesList.at(i).toIPv4Address())
        {
            ipAddress = ipAddressesList.at(i).toString();
            break;
        } 
    }

    if(!this->listen( QHostAddress(ipAddress),port ) )
    {
        qDebug() << "Could not start server";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "The server is running on\n\nIP: "<< ipAddress;
        qDebug() << "\nport: " << this->serverPort() << "\n\n";
    }
}

void MyServer::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)
{
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Connecting...";

    QAudioFormat format;

    format.setSampleRate(44100);
    format.setChannelCount(1);
    format.setSampleSize(16);
    format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt);

    QAudioDeviceInfo info = QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();
    if (!info.isFormatSupported(format))
    {
        qWarning()<<"default format not supported try to use nearest";
        format = info.nearestFormat(format);
    }

    audioInput = new QAudioInput(format, this);

    MyThread1 *thread = new MyThread1(socketDescriptor,audioInput, this);

    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    thread->start();
}
```

in file mythread.h

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtMultimediaKit/QAudioInput>

class MyThread1 : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyThread1( int ID, QAudioInput *spk, QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();

signals:
    void error(QTcpSocket::SocketError socketerror);

public slots:
    void sendData();
    void disconnected();

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;
    int socketDescriptor;
    QAudioInput *speaker;
};
#endif // MYTHREAD_H
```

in file mythread.cpp

```
#include "mythread.h"

MyThread1::MyThread1( int ID, QAudioInput *spk, QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
    this->socketDescriptor = ID;
    this->speaker = spk;
}

void MyThread1::run()
{
    qDebug() << " Thread started";

    socket = new QTcpSocket();

    if(!socket->setSocketDescriptor(this->socketDescriptor))
    {
        emit error(socket->error());
        return;
    }

    connect( speaker->start(), SIGNAL( readyRead() ), this, SLOT( sendData() ) , Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));

    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Microphone connected";

    exec();
}

void MyThread1::sendData()
{
    QByteArray Data = speaker->start()->readAll();
    QDataStream l_vStream(&Data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    l_vStream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);

    socket->write(Data, Data.length());
    socket->waitForBytesWritten();
}

void MyThread1::disconnected( )
{
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << "Mic Disconnected";

    speaker->stop();
    delete speaker;

    socket->deleteLater();
    exit(0);
}
```

in file main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <myserver.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyServer server;
    server.startServer();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't mention where is the error happens.

I'm not a Qt expert, but seems like you have to explicitly move the `QAudioInput` object to the new thread by `moveToThread()`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread

Comment: The applicatiosn compiles without errors and the server starts listening but when  a client connects I get this message.

Comment: 1. It worth mentioning it explicitly that the error is in runtime (I understood it from the error content, but maybe it isn't clear to everyone).
2. Use debugger to pinpoint where the error comes from.